# Block file for tier_prices.phtml

Tags: magento2, php, blocks, tierprice

I found `tier_prices.phtml` for the tier price display on the product detail page, but I can't find the right block file for `tier_prices.phtml`. which block file is responsible for `tier_prices.phtml`?

Comment: Can you specify, why you lopoking block file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tier Price Block - `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render/PriceBox.php`

Tier Price Model - `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/TierPrice.php`